# Limit points of polynomial recursion

Tags: real-analysis, limits, polynomials

Is there a polynomial $p$ such that the sequence $(p_n(0))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ has infinitely many limit points ?

Here $p_{k+1}(x) = p(p_{k}(x))$

---

What I know so far -

1) The set of limit points (if there are any) are in a bounded interval.

Indeed this is true for polynomials of degree $0$ or $1$. For polynomials of degree $2$ or above we know that for all $|y|$ sufficiently large (of course depending on the polynomial $p$) , $|p_n(y)|$ explodes to infinity.

2) If there are infinitely many  limit points ; they are in a bounded interval (from above) thus there is a "super limit point" $c$ which is point that contains a limit point in every neighbourhood surrounding it; and this $c$ is a limit point as well.

To see this we can use compactness.

Comment: Isn't $p(0)$, and hence $p_n(0)$ just the constant term of the polynomial? Why does the degree matter then?

Comment: Not necessarily. Take $p(x) = x^2+1$ we have $p(0) = 1$, $p_2(0) = p(p(0)) = p(1) = 2$ and so on.

Comment: I see. But what is your question exactly? Whether your proof is correct?

Comment: I don't have a proof. The terminology might be misleading to some people; Note here that $(p_n(0))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a countable set. We say that $g \in \mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ if there are infinitely many distinct elements of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ which approach arbitrarily close to $g$. That is there is a subsequence of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ which approaches to $g$

Comment: Oh, you when you said "this is true for polynomials of degree $0$ or $1$" you were referring just to that the set of limit points is in a bounded interval, not the whole claim. I see.

Comment: Related: if you allow a complex viewpoint, then yes: there are complex polynomials $p$ and points $z$ such that $(p_n(z))_{n}$ has infinitely many limit points in $\mathbb{C}$ (keyword: boundary of Siegel discs). Does it have to be $z=0$? Given that you tagged it real analysis, I am assuming you would like to have a polyomial with real coefficients, which seems considerably harder to me...

Comment: Should be real.